# C# Microsoft Identity Framework multitenant application authenticate with guest accounts

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

I'm building a multitenant application that also needs to sign guest users (users added as guests, not anonymous). The guest must be able to access resources in the tenant. For example:

- User X from Tenant A is a guest in Tenant B. Must be able to access resources in Tenant B
- User Y is an account from an external provider. It is also a guest in Tenant B. Must be able to access resources in Tenant B
- User Z is an account from an external provider. It is a guest in Tenant C. Must be able to access resources in Tenant C

Each user selects the tenant they want to interact with, so obtaining the tenantId is not an issue.

Microsoft Identity Framework really simplifies the configuration for the most common cases, but I can't find a way to configure the application with multitenant AND guest users.

My code is fairly standard:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        }
        )
```

And in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { GraphScope.FilesReadAll })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string driveId, string tenantId)
{
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { GraphScope.FilesReadAll }, tenantId: tenantId);
    //etc
}
```

I mainly followed the examples from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2)

Main problems:

- **[AuthorizeForScopes]** uses static scopes, so it is impossible to use a scope from another tenant (can't do for example {tenantUrl}/.default)
- I can't use the "common" authority (as in "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common") since I need users to get claims from a specific tenant.

I was able to use a flow similar the one for AuthorizeForScopes while obtaining the token. My idea was to return a ChallengeResult action with the specific authority, but I can't find information on how to configure it, or if that's even possible.

```
try
{
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync ...
}
catch (someAuthException)
{
    return ChallengeResult ...
}
```

Is there a way to do so, or is there a simpler way to accomplish what I try to do?

Comment: Add [AllowAnonymous].  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#disable-default-account-verification

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, but I don't want anonymous access. I want the guests to be authenticated. The main issue, as I see it, is that I have two options: using a broad authority (common, organization) or using a specific tenant. I need the second one because I want to allow (or not) access to resources in a specific tenant (yet undetermined until the user selects it) but I haven't figured out a way to dynamically specify it within the MS identity framework.

Comment: What you are saying is inconsistent.  How can a guest be authenticated when a guest does not have an account?  Only users with account can be authenticated.

Comment: @jdweng Guests are a thing in Azure. Take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal). They are different from anonymous.

Comment: I guest you have to create an account.  Anonymous you can just connect.